# Is it possible to use External Accessory Framework to make iOS device a console?

Tags: setup, pi-3, ios

I'm trying to work out a way to use my iPad to connect to as my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ before a network is set up.

There're ways I can think of:

1. Use bluetooth network tethering to create a local network - my iPad is Wifi model, so not possible
2. Use a portable 4g wireless router - extra device to take, so not favorable
3. Exploit External Accessory Framework to make an app to use pi as an external accessory through HDMI to lightening port - viable but may be impossible to do so

Is it possible to make a terminal app that uses an HDMI output source? All HDMI to lightening connectors available seem to output from lightening but not taking input, do I have to make my own connector?

Comment: Which model Raspberry Pi and do you want SSH or VNC control of the device over the network or something else?

Comment: @bmike Raspberry Pi 3 B+, please be noted that I want to do it without network, so SSH and VNC is not possible until I solve the connecting problem first...

Comment: I've also pinged the chat room over at Pi since this might really be more about how to set up a Pi... http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28765657#28765657 - As far as Ask Different - we're not for any code level programming - so this will probably be a yes/no question if there's a third party app to help set up Pi over Bluetooth or ad-hoc WiFi or a shopping question for a terminal hardware connector that uses lightning port. Basically Lightning to USB to TTL cord is your hope? https://www.adafruit.com/product/954

Comment: @bmike finding a connector is easy, but problem is, we have to have an app to interact with the input stream, iPad can't be used as a dedicated screen.

Comment: Is this for an initial RPi setup, or for an RPi that travels?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make a terminal app that uses an HDMI output source?

Of course, but I think what you mean is *input source*.  No, the HDMI cannot be used for input.

> I want to do it without network,

I think you mean without the internet or other nodes.  The simplest way in that case would just be to set up the pi as an "access point" even though it is not on a network.  Then you can connect the ipad to that.  Of course, this probably then means the ipad can't connect to anything else, so it depends on your other needs -- e.g., if you want internet access and can connect the pi via ethernet, it becomes an actual access point.

Beyond that I think you have painted your self into a corner with all the non-options.